# How to modify layout sections from included views in laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

So,
I basically have a component which requires javascript to be loaded beforehand.

master layout:

```
//layouts/master.blade.php
...
@yield('scripts')
...
@include('forms.search')
...
```

my component:

```
//forms/search.blade.php
@section('scripts')
some scripts here
@stop
...
```

what Im calling:

```
//main.blade.php
@extends('layouts.master')
```

This does not work. Section is not added to header. Am I doing something wrong or it's not possible at all with laravel?

Comment: it surely is possible, i've done it for a few times already. the problem might be with your dir structures. where is your `//layouts/master.blade.php` located? is it on `views/layouts/master.blade.php`? what does your dir structure look like?

Comment: what is the problem with structure? All is in code comments. All files are loaded by laravel, its not directory issue

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to yield the section before including. So try this.

In your **//main.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.master')
```

And in **//layouts/master.blade.php**

```
@include('forms.search')
```

And **//forms/search.blade.php**

```
   some scripts here
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling

```
@extends('layouts.master')
```

which has a

```
@yield('scripts')
```

but you are declaring the section scripts on `forms/search.blade.php`

so if you examine correctly, you are declaring scripts on the wrong blade template OR you have put the yield area on the wrong blade template.. because since the @yield is on the `layouts/master.blade.php`, it had been executed already before the @include, which does not extend anything so declaring @section there wouldn't matter.

to achieve what you want, the

```
@section('scripts')
some scripts here
@stop
```

section should be in the `main.blade.php` file..

if i'm gonna do that, it would be something like this:

**layouts/master.blade.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- more stuff here -->

        @yield('scripts')
        <!-- or put it in the footer if you like -->
    </head>
    <body>
        @yield('search-form')
        @yield('content')
    </body>
</html>
```

**forms/search.blade.php**

```
//do whatever here
```

**main.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts/master')

@section('scripts')
    {{ HTML::script('assets/js/search-form.js') }}
@stop

@section('search-form')
    @include('forms/search')
@stop
```

OR remove the `@yield('search-form')` totally on **master.blade.php** and on **main.blade.php** do this:

```
@section('scripts')
    {{ HTML::script('assets/js/search-form.js') }}
@stop

@section('content')
    @include('forms/search')
    <!-- other stuff here -->
@stop
```

Comment: you know, the problem is that Search Form and Main template are not related. Main template can live without this form and form can be in any other place I need. So as I understood there is no way to do this in master template..

Comment: the first version can live without the form though. you can also include templates on the controller level, if that is what you want. you just prepare what content will yield using a container like [this](http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-controller-and-route-layouts) then prepare one sub-layout with a search form and one without it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, What got it working for me was adding "@parent" to ALL my sections...

```
{{-- Main area where you want to "yield" --}}
@section('js')
@show

@section('js')
  @parent

  {{-- Code Here --}}
@stop
```